# Specifying default extensions in angular2 and ng2-table

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am trying to use ng2-table in my angular2 project. I installed angular2 and ng2-table using npm, when I run my app I get this 404 errors.

[image]

But the files exist in my project!
[image]

the server is looking for files with no extension, is there any way to specify default extension?

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms'; // <-- NgModel lives here
import {Ng2TableModule} from "ng2-table";

import { JobsComponent }  from './components/jobs/jobs.component';
import { JobsTable }  from './components/jobs/jobs.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, // <-- import the FormsModule before binding with [(ngModel)]
    Ng2TableModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    JobsComponent,
    JobsTable
  ],
  bootstrap: [ JobsComponent,JobsTable ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

jobs.components.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'jobs',
    templateUrl: "./jobs.html"
})
export class JobsComponent {
}

export class JobsTable implements OnInit{

    public rows:Array<any> = [];
    public columns:Array<any> = [
        {title: 'Name', name: 'name', filtering: {filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by name'}},
        {
            title: 'Position',
            name: 'position',
            sort: false,
            filtering: {filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by position'}
        },
        {title: 'Office', className: ['office-header', 'text-success'], name: 'office', sort: 'asc'},
        {title: 'Extn.', name: 'ext', sort: '', filtering: {filterString: '', placeholder: 'Filter by extn.'}},
        {title: 'Start date', className: 'text-warning', name: 'startDate'},
        {title: 'Salary ($)', name: 'salary'}
    ];
    public page:number = 1;
    public itemsPerPage:number = 10;
    public maxSize:number = 5;
    public numPages:number = 1;
    public length:number = 0;

    public config:any = {
        paging: true,
        sorting: {columns: this.columns},
        filtering: {filterString: ''},
        className: ['table-striped', 'table-bordered']
    };

    private data:Array<any> = null;

    public constructor() {
        this.length = this.data.length;
    }

    public ngOnInit():void {
        this.onChangeTable(this.config);
    }

    public changePage(page:any, data:Array<any> = this.data):Array<any> {
        let start = (page.page - 1) * page.itemsPerPage;
        let end = page.itemsPerPage > -1 ? (start + page.itemsPerPage) : data.length;
        return data.slice(start, end);
    }

    public changeSort(data:any, config:any):any {
        if (!config.sorting) {
            return data;
        }

        let columns = this.config.sorting.columns || [];
        let columnName:string = void 0;
        let sort:string = void 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            if (columns[i].sort !== '' && columns[i].sort !== false) {
                columnName = columns[i].name;
                sort = columns[i].sort;
            }
        }

        if (!columnName) {
            return data;
        }

        // simple sorting
        return data.sort((previous:any, current:any) => {
            if (previous[columnName] > current[columnName]) {
                return sort === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
            } else if (previous[columnName] < current[columnName]) {
                return sort === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
    }

    public changeFilter(data:any, config:any):any {
        let filteredData:Array<any> = data;
        this.columns.forEach((column:any) => {
            if (column.filtering) {
                filteredData = filteredData.filter((item:any) => {
                    return item[column.name].match(column.filtering.filterString);
                });
            }
        });

        if (!config.filtering) {
            return filteredData;
        }

        if (config.filtering.columnName) {
            return filteredData.filter((item:any) =>
                item[config.filtering.columnName].match(this.config.filtering.filterString));
        }

        let tempArray:Array<any> = [];
        filteredData.forEach((item:any) => {
            let flag = false;
            this.columns.forEach((column:any) => {
                if (item[column.name].toString().match(this.config.filtering.filterString)) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            });
            if (flag) {
                tempArray.push(item);
            }
        });
        filteredData = tempArray;

        return filteredData;
    }

    public onChangeTable(config:any, page:any = {page: this.page, itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage}):any {
        if (config.filtering) {
            Object.assign(this.config.filtering, config.filtering);
        }

        if (config.sorting) {
            Object.assign(this.config.sorting, config.sorting);
        }

        let filteredData = this.changeFilter(this.data, this.config);
        let sortedData = this.changeSort(filteredData, this.config);
        this.rows = page && config.paging ? this.changePage(page, sortedData) : sortedData;
        this.length = sortedData.length;
    }

    public onCellClick(data: any): any {
        console.log(data);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding some few lines to systemjs.config.js,

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/animations'                 : 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
        'ng2-table'                         : 'npm:ng2-table/ng2-table.js',
        'systemjs'                         : 'npm:systemjs/dist/systemjs.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
     ...... 
      .....
      // this specify default extension for ng2-table
      'ng2-table': {
          format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```